# how to disable this jquery function on windows width < 500px

Tags: jquery, css

I have used add and remove class function for my logo,

I want to disable that function when windows width < 500px,

here is the script i have used.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('header').addClass('sticky');
        $('#logo').addClass('none');
        $('#logo-black').removeClass('none');
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
                $('#logo').removeClass('none');
        $('#logo-black').addClass('none');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.innerWidth` to calculate the width of the window, excluding toolbar and scrollbars.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {

    if (window.innerWidth < 500) return; // Use this

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('header').addClass('sticky');
        $('#logo').addClass('none');
        $('#logo-black').removeClass('none');
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
                $('#logo').removeClass('none');
        $('#logo-black').addClass('none');
    }
});
```

Comment: `window.innerWidth` does not exclude a vertical scrollbar if present, but `document.documentElement.clientWidth` does.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the window width inside the handler.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
   if($(window).width() >= 500){
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('header').addClass('sticky');
        $('#logo').addClass('none');
        $('#logo-black').removeClass('none');
     } else {
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
        $('#logo').removeClass('none');
        $('#logo-black').addClass('none');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition

```
if($(window).width() > 500 ) {
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
       if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
           $('header').addClass('sticky');
           $('#logo').addClass('none');
           $('#logo-black').removeClass('none');
       } else {
           $('header').removeClass('sticky');
           $('#logo').removeClass('none');
           $('#logo-black').addClass('none');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Javascript when this is possible in css. I'm assuming that you are looking for fixed header. We can handle this in css only by the use of media query. Have a look at this.

```css
.header{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}
body{
  height:1000px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header{
    position:relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  sticky header
</div>
```

If you are really interested towards javascript then just check for the window width in resize like this.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 500 ){
        //code goes here
  }
});
```